# My input tag becomes empty when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, html

I made a form which add some input when I click on a button. The function of this button was made with javascript.

But when I click on it, all my inputs become empty and I don't want that. I want to keep information in inputs I already have.

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

```js
var div = document.getElementById('participant');

function AjoutParticipant() {
  var ex = document.getElementsByClassName("bouton_plus");
  for (i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
    ex[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  div.innerHTML += '<label>Nom :</label><input type="text" name="nom[]" />' +
    '<label id="pre-decal">Prenom :</label><input type="text" name="prenom[]" />' +
    '<label id="ent-decal">Entreprise :</label><input type="text" name="entreprise" /><br/>' +
    '<button class="bouton_plus" type="button" onclick="AjoutParticipant()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Ajouter Participant</button>'
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="participant">
  <legend>Participant(s)</legend>
  <label>Nom :</label><input type="text" name="nom[]" />
  <label>Prenom :</label><input type="text" name="prenom[]" />
  <label>Entreprise :</label><input type="text" name="entreprise" /><br/>
  <button class="bouton_plus" type="button" onclick="AjoutParticipant()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Ajouter Participant</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the `innerHTML` of the div, appending some new HTML to it, then assigning it back.

The `value` *attribute* in HTML represents the *default* value, so it doesn't get updated when the user types something into it.

Consequently, you reset the inputs to the default value when you overwrite the `innerHTML`.

---

**Don't use `innerHTML`**.

Instead, use DOM methods like `createElement` and `appendChild` to add new content to the div without rewriting the existing content.